# How do I make Scanner.next() preserve the last "\n"?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I have a file with the contents `"hi there tom!\n"`. That is, there is a newline character at the very end of the file.

When this code is run on that file:

```
File file = new File(path.toString());
String content = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

The trailing `\n` isn't present in `content`. How do I cause the `\n` to be kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Scanner.useDelimiter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)) interprets its argument as a [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (a regular expression). And to quote from the API documentation for `Pattern`:

> ## Summary of regular-expression constructs
>
> **Boundary matchers**
>
> - `\Z` – The end of the input but for the final terminator, if any
> - `\z` – The end of the input

Thus, in order to read to the end of the file without ignoring the last line terminator, change the argument to `useDelimiter()` from `"\\Z"` to `"\\z"`.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of nextLine() instead of next() to consume `\n` character at the end of each line.